# How to keep the order of json dictionary in ios?

Tags: ios, json, swift, dictionary

I have an issue with dealing with JSON dictionary

I am receiving a JSON response from the backend like this:

```
{
  "item x": 2,
  "item y":5,
  "item w":7,
  "item z":1,
}
```

It is displayed on the website and android app in the same order.
But when I display it on iOS (Swift 3) as NSDictionary, It is not displayed in the same order

I'm aware that the dictionary is an un-ordered list, but is there any way to keep the data as it is received from the backend whithout changing anything from the backend.

Comment: do you using "for loop"?

Comment: Dictionaries have no order. Sort them when you display

Comment: If the order is important don't use dictionary.